# Filter daterange with other daterange

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a dataset, containing min. and max. dates for each row.

What would be the best syntax for Amazon Redshift/Postgres to mark the rows, if they are in a certain timerange?

Here's a little Excel example for better understanding:
[image]

Comment: Would be quite easy in Postgres using a daterange, but I don't think that's available in redshift

Comment: Does `(startdate, enddate) overlaps (date '2020-11-01', date '2020-11-30')` work in Redshift? (It's not completely the same as "included" in the same range, but might be enough)